# What is the grade of the hadith: "If the people of Syria are corrupted, there will be no good in you"?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

> Qurrah ibn Iyas reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “If the people of Syria are corrupted, there will be no good in you. A group among my nation will continue to be supported, unharmed by those who fail them until the establishment of the Hour.”

Source: [Sunan al-Tirmidhī](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/35)

Can some one please tell me the grade of this hadith?

Comment: There are many ahadith with the same wording but a different location: I've heard it referring to the people of Maghreb, Syria, 'Iraq, Yemen, Hijaz, etc. and there's also a hadith imam Malik used to refer to when asked to leave Medina saying something like "... Medina is better for them". The hadith was graded as hassan by the hadith scholar Darrussalm is relying on, but I personally doubt any hadith saying that a location (except with Mecca, maybe Medina) or people of a "certain -named- location" have any specific virtues, as we know people and their attitude change by time.

Answer (score 1):

The Hadith has been classed as Hassan Sahih by Tirmidhi. It is include by Ibn Hibban in his [Sahih](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31691/14725#p1). It is classed as Sahih by Al-Albani in [Silsilat As-Saheehah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/9442/760#p7) and by Al Arna'ut in his classification of [Musnad Ahmad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/11913#p1) and by Zubair Ali Za'i in his classification of [Tirmidhi](https://archive.org/stream/JamiAtTirmidhiarabic-English6VolumesPublishedByDarussalam/JamiAt-tirmidhiVol.4-1897-2605EnglishArabic#page/n251/mode/2up).

Answer (score -1):

I dont like to affirm or deny particular hadiths, but it may be that a lot of the hadiths about Syria were notions that came about later due to the conflict between Ali and Muawiya. Muawiya's rule was in Damascus.